# How do you define a paper type for a printer in IBM i on the AS/400

Tags: ibm-midrange

Problem: We print stickers to our copier from the AS/400 that contain barcodes. When the printer tray is set to plain paper, the stickers print without any user intervention but the barcodes come out incomplete and blotched. After changing the paper tray to a Thick paper setting, the job from the AS/400 requires user intervention. The copier no longer knows what tray to print the stickers from. The reason being is the AS/400 is telling the copier that the job is set to use plain paper and the copier has no matching trays with that size and paper type. This issue only happens when trying to use the Thick paper type so that the barcodes come out complete and scannable.

The answer we are looking for: Is there a way to specify the paper type or paper density on the printer itself in wrkcfgsts *dev "Printer". Or is there an option to change the setting of the paper type or density in the form editor for the job that is configured?

This process works from the Windows side if we specify the paper type in the print preferences. Anything printer will print automatically without user intervention.

What setting would need to be changed in order to get the copier to recognize the print job that the AS/400 is sending and for the settings between the two to be consistent?

Comment: Not a development related question.  Better suited to https://serverfault.com/ or [midrange.com mailing list](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/midrange-l)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check how PSF configuration is added for the printer using DSPPSFCFG (Display PSF Configuration)

DSPPSFCFG PSFCFG(*PSF Config Name*)

You should have the below options.

PDF paper size drawer 1  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *LETTER
PDF paper size drawer 2  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *A4

See if this is what you are looking for.